# Insert HTML data into the SQL Server

Tags: html, sql-server, insert-update

I have a problem about inserting HTML data into SQL Server. here are the details:

this is my stored procedure;

```
@articleID int,
@articleBody nvarchar(max)
AS

UPDATE v2_Articles SET articleBody = @articleBody WHERE articleID = @articleID
```

and this is my asp code for inserting data;

```
x_articleBody = Replace(Replace(Request.Form("x_articleBody"), CHR(34), """"), "'", """")

Connection.Open(ConnStr)
Connection.Execute("EXEC InsertBody @articleID = " & aID & ", _
@articleBody = '" & x_articleBody & "'")            
Connection.Close()
```

and this is my data for insert;

```
<font> TEXT TEXT &nbsp;&nbsp; TEXT TEXT</font>
```

So, problem is: when I try this, data saving until

```
&nbsp;
```

it means after the process sql table is changing like;

```
<font> TEXT TEXT
```

Is there any idea about that?

*ps. I'm using nicedit text editor for generating html data.*

Comment: This is all kinds of bad. Why save HTML in a database? Are you validating your arguments? How do you keep from saving malicious HTML? You should use an sproc and not dynamic SQL. Etc. etc.

Comment: because no one can insert any malicious HTML, this is local application and none of pages accessible except admin=))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use embedded SQL - you are causing yourself extra headaches by doing that, because you have to go through this data cleansing mess and you're exposing your application to potential [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

Create a stored procedure that takes text as a parameter, and use that to save your HTML markup.

Comment: thank you Kon, could you please advise about taking text as a parameter=)